# letter-spacing calculated as default, but is changing depending on page on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an element with text and a break tag.

```
<div id="mobile-menu-button-a" class="mobile-menu-bar-item">
    Rubber<br />
    Stamps
</div>
```

It is changing letter-spacing from one page to the next ever so slightly on Chrome. Below it is visible between the letter `b`s.

[image: First Example]

[image: Second Example]

This is causing a visible shift in the navigation bar.

I have looked at the inspect element and there is no computer `letter-spacing` in either instance.

[image: Computed Style]

I have tried setting this style, but it did not resolve the issue.

```
.mobile-menu-bar-item {
    letter-spacing: initial;
}
```

I have also tried using an approach that did not use the break tag, but this did not resolve the issue either.

```
<div id="mobile-menu-button-a" class="mobile-menu-bar-item">
    <span>Rubber</span>
    <span>Stamps</span>
</div>

.mobile-menu-bar-item span {
    display: block;
}
```

**What could be causing this shift in letters?**

It is a large HTML document, but will post code that may be relevant as requested.